# State gets currupted when using SimpleDialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to write a todo app in flutter. My idea is that when you click on a tag of a todo you can edit the tags of the todo.

Removing tags works flawlessly, but when i use `TextField` to add tags and press on the submit button on the keyboard weird things happen. The "tag" i typed into the `TextField` gets added to the list of tags and appears for removal (but only for a split second). Also the `TextField` gets cleared but the additional tag is gone and disappears from the list of tags. 
Actually the whole `TagsEditor` gets reset. So the old tags reappear even if i already removed them. Very weird...

After some experimenting I found out that with the keyboard going away the `TagsEditor` gets reset. What reason could that possibly have? How can i prevent that?

```
class TagsEditor extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> tags;

  TagsEditor({this.tags});

  @override
  _TagsEditorState createState() => _TagsEditorState();
}


class _TagsEditorState extends State<TagsEditor> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tagAddController = new TextEditingController();
    return SimpleDialog(
      title: Text("Tags"),
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: tagAddController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'this is a tag',
                  labelText: 'add tag',
                ),
                maxLines: 1,
                onSubmitted: (String tag) {
                  setState(() { 
                    widget.tags.add(tag);
                    tagAddController.text = "";
                  });
                  print(widget.tags);
                },
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200.0,
                width: 300.0,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  itemCount: widget.tags.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return OutlineButton(
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),),
                          Text(widget.tags[index]),
                        ],
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          widget.tags.removeAt(index);
                        });
                        print(widget.tags);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("cancel"),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, null),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("submit"),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, widget.tags),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ]
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[an image of the actual app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQrrF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `final tagAddController = new TextEditingController();` out of the build method.

```
class _TagsEditorState extends State<TagsEditor> {
  final tagAddController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

**What's happening**

You're creating the text controller every time the app is built. The app builds when you call `setState()` for example (it rebuilds for more reasons too, that's just one example). Every time you call `setState`, the build method gets called and therefore resets the form field value since you're recreating the value.

**Important!**

The reason why when the keyboard goes away, the `TagsEditor` gets reset is because the app rebuilds when the keyboard goes away, another reason why the `build` method gets called and since you're recreating the `TextEditingController`, it resets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now when i dismiss the keyboard, the text is still there. Unfortunately everything still resets when i press on the submit button. It shows the state it was in when it first showed up. I find it really weird. Maybe it is a bug or weird interactions.

Comment: What's supposed to happen when you press the submit button?

Comment: When the submit button is pressed, a new `OutlineButton` with the tag that was typed into the `TextField` is supposed to be added. Well i fixed it now. It turns out `TextEditController` sould not be `final` and that i was looking for `onEditingComplete` not `onSubmitted`. In addition my usage `showDialog()` seemed to cause additional issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)